# Slide out menu android java

Tags: java, android, menu, slide

I made an application for my Samsung device. Samsung phones generally have a menu button on the bottom side of the phone which is a problem for those devices who do not. I tried my app out on a Nexus, but since it did not have the physical menu button, I couldn't open the menu.

Now I want to make another option to to open the menu in my app. I though a slide out menu would be nice. I want to use the same menu but another way to open it. I want to be able to open it from the side of the screen by swiping to the right, and from the menu button.

P.S. Normally there is a titlebar on top of the screen in an app with a menu button/option on it to. But I hide my titlebar (in my AndroidManifest), so that's the issue why I need another solution..

Comment: Have you used Navigation Drawer. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: @vjdhama I downloaded the example, NavigationDrawer.zip. When I open the app, I can slide out a menu from the left side.. That's exactly how I want it.. But on the bottom, and I want to slide out my original ItemMenu. Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Navigation Drawers](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) for slide out menu. You can use Navigation for two menus, one from left other from right using different listview.

If you want to design a custom slide out menu using navigation drawer here is a tutorial.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Thanks, yes I'll a slide-out menu.. That cames out of the bottom of my screen by sliding! :-) I'll read the url's you post! Thanks,

Comment: Upvote and accept the post if you like it, so as to close the thread.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: What if I don't wish to use the slideout menu for navigation purposes?